# How to use both English and French QnaMaker on Azure Bot Service at the same time?

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, chatbot, azure-qna-maker

We have a chatbot and a button beside it which can change the language of bot between English and French. I also have a QnAmaker contains both English and French questions. Is there a way for us to only handle English questions when bot is at English mode? Same goes to French.

```
Note: my bot react like this:
    user: what is teww?
                       Do you mean this, select one of question below: BOT
                         1. French question
                         2. English question
                         3  French question
```

I want prevent this from happening, I am thinking about creating two qnamaker one for french one for english. however I don't know to handle this qna changes in the azure bot service? is there a way to work around it?

Platform: Azure Bot Service
          Node.JS
          Microsoft QnA Maker

Comment: Documentation from https://qnamaker.ai/Documentation/Faqs clearly states "If you have content from multiple languages, be sure to create a separate service for each language." each service has different ids, so you will have one dialog per language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can create 2 QnAMaker knowledge bases individual for your English and French questions. And you can leverage [**Text Analytics API**](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/TextAnalytics.V2.0/operations/56f30ceeeda5650db055a3c7) to detect user input language in bot's `recevie` middleware which shows at [Determine the locale by using analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-localization#determine-the-locale-by-using-analytics).

Please refer to the following code snippet:

```
var recognizer1 = new cognitiveservices.QnAMakerRecognizer({
    knowledgeBaseId: <knowledgeBaseId_1>,
    subscriptionKey: <subscriptionKey_1>,
    top: 4
});

var basicQnAMakerDialog = new cognitiveservices.QnAMakerDialog({
    recognizers: [recognizer1],
    qnaThreshold: 0.3,
});
var recognizer2 = new cognitiveservices.QnAMakerRecognizer({
    knowledgeBaseId: <knowledgeBaseId_2>,
    subscriptionKey: <subscriptionKey_2>,
    top: 4
});

var basicQnAMakerDialog2 = new cognitiveservices.QnAMakerDialog({
    recognizers: [recognizer2],
    qnaThreshold: 0.3,
});

bot.dialog('en', basicQnAMakerDialog);
bot.dialog('zh', basicQnAMakerDialog2);

bot.dialog('/', [(session, args) => {
    switch (session.preferredLocale()) {
        case 'zh':
            session.replaceDialog('zh', args)
            break;
        case 'en-US':
        default:
            session.replaceDialog('en', args)
            break;
    }
}])

bot.use({
    receive: function (event, next) {
        if (event.text) {
            var options = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'https://westus2.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/languages?numberOfLanguagesToDetect=1',
                body: {
                    documents: [{
                        id: 'message',
                        text: event.text
                    }]
                },
                json: true,
                headers: {
                    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '230f82f08c014accbd067ddc2c0ea98f'
                }
            };
            request(options, function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error && body) {
                    if (body.documents && body.documents.length > 0) {
                        var languages = body.documents[0].detectedLanguages;
                        if (languages && languages.length > 0) {
                            event.textLocale = languages[0].iso6391Name;
                        }
                    }
                }
                next();
            });
        } else {
            next();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help.